Adding padding within a subplot
Can someone tell me what I need to do to change the padding within the boundary of a subplot in Julia? Just need to know how to make the border larger so the 8 doesn't overlap for example in this mwe:
  function addlabels(x,y)
    for i in range(1,length(x))
        plt.text(i,y[i]+0.2,y[i],fontsize=40, ha = "center")
    end
    end
   
       plt.figure(figsize=(18,18))
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2,                    
                    top=0.8,
                    #wspace=0.4, 
                    hspace=0.8)
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
    y=[3,4,3,8,2]
            b = PyPlot.bar(x,y,color="#0f87bf",align="center",alpha=0.4)
        addlabels(x,y)

            plt.xticks(fontsize=14, fontname="arial", rotation=80)
            plt.yticks(fontsize=14,fontname="arial", )



Adjust the limits of the y-axis?

plt.margins(y=0.3)
